# Print out string with spaces

Tags: nasm

I am trying to loop through a string in nasm and printing it back out with a space in between each character and incrementing any digit less than 9 by 1.

So for example; if I type in command line;

```
str1 Hello8
str1 1234
str1 9
```

The output should be;

```
H e l l o 9
1 2 3 4
9
```

I've managed to print out the first two arguments;

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
global asm_main

section .data

section .bss

section .text

asm_main:
  enter 0, 0
  pusha

  mov eax, dword [ebp+8]  ; argc
  call print_int          ; display argc
  call print_nl

  mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]  ; address of argv[]
  mov eax, dword [ebx]     ; get argv[0] argument -- ptr to string
  call print_string        ; display argv[0] arg
  call print_nl

  mov eax, dword [ebx+4]   ; get argv[1] argument -- ptr to string
  call print_string        ; display argv[1] arg
  call print_nl

  mov eax, dword [ebx+8]   ; get argv[2] argument -- ptr to string
  call print_string        ; display argv[1] arg
  call print_nl

  popa
  leave
  ret
```

Thank you for time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a `print_char` in `asm_io.inc` that prints `al`:

```
        mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]  ; address of argv[]
        mov esi, dword [ebx+4]   ; get argv[1] argument -- ptr to string
   l:   lodsb                    ; al = [esi++]
        or al, al                ; if 0 we reached end of string
        jz end

        ; check if al is a digit
        cmp al, '0'
        jb continue
        cmp al, '9'
        jae continue
        inc al                   ; al was '0'..'8', now '1'..'9'
   continue:

        call print_char          ; print the char
        mov al, ' '             
        call print_char          ; print the space
        jmp l
    end:

        call print_nl
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very kind of you but it also needs to increment any numbers. How would I do that?

Comment: Updated the answer. Btw, it will also change `1234` to `2 3 4 5`.

Comment: Thank you! That's great. Again, very kind of you to do this. Your help was much appreciated.

Comment: @user4179157 : If this answer ends up solving your problem, consider accepting it as an answer. More on the how and why of accepting and answers can be found here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Comment: I learned quite alot! Thanks again, just one last question, I promise, if I wanted to print the length of the string, how would I do that? Thanks you!

Comment: Put `xor edx, edx` and `inc edx` before and after the `l:` to count the string length. You figure out if there's a function to print numbers in the `inc` file, okay?

Comment: Okay, and thank you Kenney! Please live long! I will have more questions for you in the future.