# How to print spaces between two letters in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

refer to the following code which i have written :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *a[])

{
int i, j;
for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
{
    printf("");
    for(j=5;j>=1;j--)
    {
        printf("%c",'A'-1 + j);
        printf("");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

this code prints the pattern as :
EDCBA

EDCBA

EDCBA

EDCBA

EDCBA

but i want output something like :
E D C B A

E D C B A

E D C B A

E D C B A

E D C B A

can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Use `printf("%-2c",'A'-1 + j);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print out string with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964811/print-out-string-with-spaces)

Comment: The second `printf` in the loop does not print anything. You forgot something.

Answer (score 2):

Use space:

```
printf(" ");
```

instead of

```
printf("");
```

Like,

```
for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
{
    printf(" ");
    for(j=5;j>=1;j--)
    {
        printf("%c",'A'-1 + j);
        printf("");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a left-justified minimum field width of 2 with `%-2c`. And remove the zero-length format specifiers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *a[])

{
    int i, j;
    for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=5;j>=1;j--)
        {
            printf("%-2c",'A'-1 + j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```